# Vue.js - how to pass props to component elements with slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Am trying to pass props from a component element that contains a slot

**PatientBooking.vue**

```
<user-profile :titlename="BOOKINGDETAIL">
  <div class="block">
    <div>Ereferral: 84884jjd</div>
    <div>Gender: Male</div>
    <div>Height: 84</div>
  </div>
</user-profile>
```

**UserProfile.vue**

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="block">
    <template v-if="titlename == 'BOOKINGDETAIL'">BOOKING DETAIL</template>
    <template v-else-if="titlename == 'BOOKING'">BOOKING</template>
    <template v-else>RESULT DETAIL</template>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</div>

export default {
  name: "UserProfile",
  props: {
    titlename: {
      type: String,
      default: ""
    }
  }
}
```

Now whenever I bind the `user-profile` component with `titlename` props with any word it doesn't goes into the `UserProfile` component, it always default to empty string which displays RESULT DETAIL.

Please I need help on how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) like so :

**UserProfile.vue**

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="block">
    <template v-if="titlename == 'BOOKINGDETAIL'">BOOKING DETAIL</template>
    <template v-else-if="titlename == 'BOOKING'">BOOKING</template>
    <template v-else>RESULT DETAIL</template>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <slot :title="titlename"></slot>
  </div>
</div>
```

**PatientBooking.vue**

```
<user-profile :titlename="BOOKINGDETAIL">
 <template v-slot:default="slotProps">
  <div class="block">
   // use slotProps.title to get access to titlename passed via slots
    <div>Ereferral: 84884jjd</div>
    <div>Gender: Male</div>
    <div>Height: 84</div>
  </div>
</template>
</user-profile>
```